# install basic applications on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, ubuntu-12.10

I have just installed ubuntu 12.10 (without internet at the time of installation), and even some basic applications like vim are not installed in it.
What should I do so that these applications (which I guess, would have been installed if I were to install with internet) ?

Comment: open software centre and install the things you want. Or open a ternimal and type: sudo apt-get install [the thing you want]

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ubuntu Software Center for installing apps. Some basic apps are Libre Office,Document Viewer, Empathy, Thunderbird,Firefox etc

Answer (score 0):

The software updater will get your system where it is supposed to be. Or use command line to `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` to get current.

Ubuntu should have vim-tiny installed by default. I only use vi. You are typing `vi` to run it, yes? I just typed `vim` in the CLI and the response suggested I install it. The fix for that is to make a soft link to vim from vi: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/vi /usr/bin/vim`